# Angular success function called before http.get function returns

Tags: javascript, angularjs, promise, angular-promise

I have an angular controller which makes an HTTP GET request and on the promise return, calls either a success of error function. My code right now will sometimes execute the success function after the GET request returns and sometime execute before it. Is there something I'm messing up in my promise handling? Something to note, sometimes the http GET doesn't even get called (or at least its breakpoint) and the success function happens regardless. Here is my code:

```
.controller('CheckOutCtrl', ['$scope', '$http', function($scope, $http) {
    //Controller for checkout feature
    $scope.owner = "Unclaimed"; //Default owner
    $scope.endDate = "";
    $scope.unclaimed = true;
    $scope.showpopup = false; //Should we show the popup that checkout is successful or returned
    $scope.currentOwner = false; //Show return date
    $scope.popuptext = "";

    $scope.checkOut = function(){ //Extends or creates a check out
        $http.get("/checkout/extend/code/" + code + "/username/" + userName).then(
            function success(response, status, headers, config) {
                console.log("Checked out or extended");
                $scope.showpopup = true;
                $scope.currentOwner = true;
                $scope.popuptext = response.data; //Show airport checked out until or error
                console.log($scope.popuptext);
                init(); //Update current owner
            },
            function error(response, status, headers, config) {
                $scope.error = response;
                console.error("Check out error:", response);
            }
        );
    };
}
```

Comment: try this way instead `.then(function(success){ console.log(success.data)}, function(e) { console.log(e) }`

Comment: @AshikBasheer That has the same issue

Comment: where do you call checkOut function?

Comment: Don't 'code' and 'userName' become undefined? Also, is that URL correct? Check network tab for actual response

Comment: @lifetimeLearner007 The URL is correct, as are the variables. Sometimes the request goes through correctly, but most times the request is just never put through.

Comment: @AliBahrami I call it with an ng-click directive

Comment: The `.then` method only invokes the handler function with one argument (response). `status, headers, config` are ignored.

Comment: at line 11, where did you define 'code' and 'userName' ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I discovered this was happening because Angular caches GET requests for some time and the cached version of my request was being used.